# Set DisplayMemberPath for ListBoxItem's Content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, listboxitem

I'm trying to figure out how to bind a List of ListBoxItems and have the correct DisplayMemberPath be shown on my control. I need to use a list of ListBoxItems because my control is accessing properties such as ActualHeight/Width, which I lose if I bind the ItemsSource to a List of State

```
public class State
{
    public string LongName { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a AllItems, a List of State. I am populating my ListBox's ItemsSource as follows:

```
BoxItems = new ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItem>(AllItems.Select(i => new MyListBoxItem() { Content = i }).ToList());
```

I want my DisplayMemberPath to be LongName. I've tried many different ways of modifying the .xaml to properly display the LongName (New York, New Jersey, Florida, etc), but I always end up with namespace.classname in my listbox. I've attempted setting the ListBox's DisplayMemberPath and ItemsSource in the .xaml and in the .xaml.cs.

I've tried many different things such as setting the content control and adding a data template in the .xaml.

Comment: 'Content = i.LongName'

Comment: I am trying to make a generic control, which takes in a `List<object>`, so I won't know the names of the fields. I expose another property, which I use to set DisplayMemberPath.

Answer (score 2):

Creating an `ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItem>` doesn't seem to make sense.

Better bind directly to `AllItems`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"
         DisplayMemberPath="LongName"/>
```

Instead of setting `DisplayMemberPath`, you may set the `ItemTemplate` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding LongName}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: In the above code snippet it should just be `ListBoxItem`, not `MyListBoxItem`. I need to use ListBoxItems because they expose properties for Height/Width (ActualHeight and ActualWidth) which I use elsewhere in my control. If I bind just a `List<State>`, I lose these properties.

Comment: The element in the DataTemplate also has a size. And you can get an the ListBoxItem that contains a data item by the ListBox's `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` method.

Comment: Sometimes this returns null, even if the item exists in the itemsource.

Comment: Maybe due to virtualization. If you don't have a really large number of items, set `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` on the ListBox.

Comment: I've tried that. I've tried using the both `ContainerFromIndex` and `ContainerFromItem`. There's no way to get around setting the proper DisplayMemeberPath given my above scenario? If not, I think I will have to manage the values in the code behind - use reflection to get proper values and bind that string to`ListBoxItem` and keep a mapping of these values to the original items (class) passed in.

Answer (score 0):

The `DisplayMemberPath` refers to a property of the type `T` in the `IEnumerable<T>` ItemsSource of the `ListBox`. So if you set the `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItem>`, it is the `MyListBoxItem` class that must have a `LongName` property for you to be able to set the `DisplayMemberPath` property to "LongName".

> I need to use a list of ListBoxItems because my control is accessing properties such as ActualHeight/Width, which I lose if I bind the ItemsSource to a List of State.

Any item that you add to the `Items`/`ItemsSource` property that is not a `ListBoxItem` is implicitly wrapped in a `ListBoxItem` container. You can set any properties of this one using the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the `ListBox`. This means that you could add `Height` and `Width` properties to the `State` class and bind to these provided that you set the `ItemsSource` to an `IEnumerable<State>`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" DisplayMemberPath="LongName" Loaded="ListBox_Loaded">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

You could also get a reference such a container once it has been loaded, using the `ItemContainerGenerator`:

```
private void ListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in lb.Items)
    {
        var container = lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem;
        if (container != null)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the ItemsSource to an `IEnumerable<ListBoxItem>` is not a good idea.